# Generate PEM or CER file from the text of a public key

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, rsa, pem

I have a public key given in a document, in the form

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blah blah blah
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Is there a tool I can use to generate a PEM or CER file from this? I've looked into openssl, and googled around until I think I'll go crazy. It seems most people don't get the key in raw text format.

Comment: A file with the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` header is a PEM file containing a certificate. Just save it

Comment: I just wanted to say this is a reasonable question. The question asker doesn't deserve downvotes for not already knowing that text with PEM headers is what makes the PEM format. **Stack Overflow is supposed to be welcoming**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's already a .PEM file, it's just that the extension possibly doesn't match. PEM basically consists of a header and footer with base64 encoding in between (some parameters may be encoded right after the header line as well). What you are showing is the PEM header and footer line.

Comment: Embarrassingly simple. Thanks so much Maarten

Comment: Nitpick: PEM is dashed-BEGIN/END lines surrounding optional headers then base64 **with line breaks** every 76 chars (or sometimes a smaller multiple of 4). A PEM-like file with overlong lines often works some places and fails others which can be troublesome.

Comment: Thanks Dave. This bit me. Didn't realise the reason (base64 w/ line breaks), but found success echoing the text from the console into a file.

Comment: my form validation includes a check for the mime type of the file. How do you add that?

Comment: Files themselves don't have MIME types set; you'd need to map the extension to a MIME type in the OS or you could set them in a client or server through the HTTP headers. Note that `.pem` may map to different types though, certificates, keys, certificate requests and whatnot. It makes more sense to map e.g. `.cer` to a certificate.

Comment: I've seen another issue in Python where the end of lines were actually included as escapes, i.e. not the newline character but actually `\n` but in two bytes. Obviously it may be that the base 64 decoding or in this case header finding may struggle on that, especially with Python3 where there is more of a difference between byte strings and character strings.